# How can I customize arrowhead shape to match common LaTeX styles?

Tags: graphics, latex

How do I control the shape of my arrow heads? LaTeX's TikZ package has a wide variety of predefined arrowhead styles, some of which I'd like to try to match for Mathematica figures I'm importing into a LaTeX document:

[image: LaTeX arrow examples]

But Mathematica's default arrowhead style comes nowhere near any of these. For example,

```
Graphics[{Thick, Arrow[{{0, 0}, {-50, 0}}]}]
```

yields

[image: Default Mathematica arrow]

Earlier versions of Mathematica had options for controlling arrowhead shape, but those seem to be gone in 8.0.

How can I get the shape of my Mathematica arrowheads to match the LaTeX TikZ arrowhead styles?

Comment: In addition, Mathematica's arrows are scaled differently from LaTeX arrowheads, using a logic I can't discern. Ideally I'd like to also ensure that my Mathematica arrows scale the same way LaTeX arrows do; but that is perhaps a separate question.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation of `Arrowheads`?

Comment: Yes, naturally. Nothing there got me close.

Comment: The `Arrow` documentation says clearly: *The form, orientation, and position of arrowheads can be specified by an Arrowheads directive. *

Comment: @Heike: that only gives one example for a custom arrowhead, but nothing about predefined types (though `StreamPlot` has a miriad of different built-in arrow styles).

Comment: @IstvánZachar: `StreamPlot` might be a place to start. Are the built-in styles illustrated somewhere?

Comment: Under **Options** > **StreamStyle**. But these arrow styles are not implemented generally. Checking the `InputForm` of this `StreamPlot[{-1 - x^2 + y, 1 + x - y^2}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, StreamPoints -> 1, StreamScale -> {Full, All, 0.05}, StreamStyle -> "CircleArrow"]` shows that the extra features are represented as `Circle[...]` objects instead of preserving a string argument inside `Arrowheads`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Indeed; the question is _how_? The example just shows specification of position. The only other examples I can find rely on the creation of a graphic that defines the arrowhead, which begs the question: how does one define that to match a desired style?

Comment: @IstvánZachar: So I can't use them outside of `StreamPlot`?

Comment: See [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/788/121) -- it will show how to define custom shapes, *and* set absolute arrowhead sizes.

Comment: What's wrong with defining your own arrowhead? Most of the examples above won't take more than a few minutes to define.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: I'd appreciate help with that. It's taking me a lot longer than a few minutes to match the LaTeX styles above (and I get weird results: gaps between the tip of the arrow and the end of the edge, for example). Having a reference for generating matches to these commonly used styles would be pretty widely useful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here is a `Manipulate` to design yourself an `Arrow`:

```
DynamicModule[{top, baseMid, rightBase, outerMidRight, innerMidRight},
 Manipulate[
  top = {0, 0};
  baseMid = {1, 0} baseMid;
  rightBase = {1, -1} leftBase;
  outerMidRight = {1, -1} outerMidLeft;
  innerMidRight = {1, -1} innerMidLeft;
  h = Graphics[
    {
     Opacity[0.5],
     FilledCurve[
      {
       BSplineCurve[{baseMid, innerMidLeft, leftBase}],
       BSplineCurve[{leftBase, outerMidLeft, top}],
       BSplineCurve[{top, outerMidRight, rightBase}],
       BSplineCurve[{rightBase, innerMidRight, baseMid}]
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
  {{baseMid, {-2, 0}}, Locator},
  {{innerMidLeft, {-2, 0.5}}, Locator},
  {{leftBase, {-2, 1}}, Locator},
  {{outerMidLeft, {-1, 1}}, Locator}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is easy to add more control points if the need arises.

The arrowhead graphics is put in the variable `h`. Note that it contains an `Opacity` function for better visibility of the control points. You need to remove that if you want to have a fully saturated arrow head.

Some examples generated with this `Manipulate` using:

```
Graphics[
  { Arrowheads[{{Automatic, 1, h /. Opacity[_] :> Sequence[]}}],
    Arrow /@ 
        Table[{{0, 0}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi] - 2 \[Pi]/20, 2 \[Pi]/20}]
  }, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 0.2
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The code for the arrow heads can be found in `h`. Just copy the graphics or the `FullForm` to store it for later use.

```
h /. Opacity[_] :> Sequence[] // FullForm

(* ==>
Graphics[{FilledCurve[{BSplineCurve[{{-0.496, 0.}, {-1., 0.48}, {-2,1}}],            
    BSplineCurve[{{-2, 1}, {-0.548, 0.44999999999999996}, {0, 0}}], 
    BSplineCurve[{{0, 0}, {-0.548, -0.44999999999999996}, {-2, -1}}], 
          BSplineCurve[{{-2, -1}, {-1., -0.48}, {-0.496, 0.}}]}]}
]
*)
```

---

**EDIT**
One more control point will cover most common shapes:

```
DynamicModule[{top, baseMid, outerMidRight, innerMidRight, 
  innerBaseRight, outerBaseRight},
 Manipulate[
  top = {0, 0};
  baseMid = {1, 0} baseMid;
  innerBaseRight = {1, -1} innerBaseLeft;
  outerBaseRight = {1, -1} outerBaseLeft;
  outerMidRight = {1, -1} outerMidLeft;
  innerMidRight = {1, -1} innerMidLeft;
  h = Graphics[
    {
     Opacity[0.5],
     FilledCurve[
      {
       BSplineCurve[{baseMid, innerMidLeft, innerBaseLeft}],
       Line[{innerBaseLeft, outerBaseLeft}],
       BSplineCurve[{outerBaseLeft, outerMidLeft, top}],
       BSplineCurve[{top, outerMidRight, outerBaseRight}],
       Line[{outerBaseRight, innerBaseRight}],
       BSplineCurve[{innerBaseRight, innerMidRight, baseMid}]
       }
      ]
     }
    ],
  {{baseMid, {-2, 0}}, Locator},
  {{innerMidLeft, {-2, 0.5}}, Locator},
  {{innerBaseLeft, {-2, 1}}, Locator},
  {{outerBaseLeft, {-2, 1.1}}, Locator},
  {{outerMidLeft, {-1, 1}}, Locator}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Amazing! Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

One source of arrowhead shapes is `Graph` which comes with a list of predefined arrowhead shapes that you can set using the option `EdgeShapeFunction`. You can get the names of these shapes by doing something like

```
arrowheadNames = GraphElementData["Edge"];
```

Unfortunately, these names by themselves are useless in `Arrowheads`. Luckily there is a way to extract the `Graphics` specifications of these arrowheads by converting a `Graph` to `Graphics` using `Show` and extracting the `Arrowheads` directives:

```
headlist = 
  Flatten[Cases[
      Show[Graph[{1 <-> 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> #]], 
      Arrowheads[a_] :> 
       Cases[a, b_GraphicsBox :> ToExpression[b], Infinity, 1], 
      Infinity, 1] & /@ arrowheadNames];

GraphicsGrid[Partition[headlist, 5, 5, {1, 1}, ""], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can use these in `Arrowheads` as follows:

```
grlist = Graphics[{Arrowheads[{{.3, 1, #}}], Arrow[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}] & /@ headlist;

GraphicsGrid[Partition[grlist, 5, 5, {1, 1}, ""], Frame -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I can't get this code to work anymore.

Comment: Same here, on Mathematica 10.1, this code does not work anymore.

Comment: For this to work in Mathematica 10, replace the `GraphicsBox` with `Graphics`: `headlist = 
  Flatten[Cases[
      Show[Graph[{1 \[DirectedEdge] 2}, EdgeShapeFunction -> #]], 
      Arrowheads[a_] :> Cases[a, _Graphics, Infinity, 1], Infinity, 
      1] & /@ arrowheadNames];`

Comment: There is a mistyping, Headlist is written at the beginning with a small l “Headlist” at the end with a capital L “HeadList”...

Comment: I've fixed it, @Phil.