# Scaling edge thicknesses

Tags: graphics, scaling

---

**UPDATE**

There may be some confusion as to the specification of the problem. kguler's answer doesn't really answer the question. I'll try to elaborate a bit at **the bottom of the post**.

---

One problem with the solutions of the [custom arrow shaft question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11545/57) is the specification of the edge thickness. In the design of the arrows, the thickness of the edge *in relation to the overall size of the arrow* is part of the effect one wants to achieve.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Unfortunately, the two methods that can be used to specify the edge thickness, namely `Thickness` and `AbsoluteThickness` are not sufficient for this goal. As an easy illustration of the problem, I'll draw some circles here.

**Thickness**

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image]

Add some **identical (!)** copies of the same circle:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], 
         Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The number in the `Thickness` specification is a fraction of the horizontal image extent.

**AbsoluteThickness**

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[20], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, let's reduce the image size:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[20], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 70]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In both cases, the ratio between the edge thickness and the object size changes. Sometimes that may be desirable, but here it isn't.

What is needed is either a thickness specification that is related to object size or a status variable from which the current image extent can be read, so that with known object size the edge thickness can be scaled. The latter would be something akin to `CurrentValue` or so.

Something self-referential like

```
pl = Graphics[{Text[Norm@PlotRange[pl][[2]] // Dynamic, {10, 10}]}]
```

could work, but is rather ugly and, frankly, scary. When I changed `PlotRange` to `ImageSize` I got my frontend hanging.

Any ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

Trying to further clarify the question.

---

First, some definitions:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We have one or more objects with a given **object size**. In this case, circles with a radius of one. This size is given in Mathematica's internal, dimensionless canvas coordinate system.

We want to specify the **object edge thickness** in terms of this object size. However, MMA doesn't have that capability. You have to either specify the `EdgeForm` as `Thickness` (which measures edge thickness as a fraction of the horizontal `PlotRange`) or as `AbsoluteThickness` (which measures edge thickness in terms of printer's points, 1/72 of an inch).

The `PlotRange` is the dimensionless size of MMA's canvas as displayed in the figure. It is fully independent of the `ImageSize`, which determines the graphics's physical size in printer's points.

This leads to the following problem :

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both figures have the same `ImageSize`, but the `PlotRange` has increased (more of MMA's internal canvas is revealed), which means that edge thickness related to object size increases too, since the thickness in canvas terms increases whereas the object remains at the same canvas size. The circle's edge now takes up most of the circle's area, which wasn't the case before.

If we specify thickness with `AbsoluteThickness` we get:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[10], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[10], Blue}], 
          Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, the edge thickness *in points* remains the same, but the object size in points decreases because the `ImageSize` in points is the same, but more objects have to be fitted in that same space, so they get less points allotted per object. Again, the edge thickness related to the object size changes.

Introducing `ThicknessC` as the desired edge thickness and `ObjectSizeC` the object size, both in canvas terms, we have

```
ThicknessC = C*ObjectSizeC
```

with C the desired constant ratio of these two variables. C is responsible for the appearance of the object. For instance, we might want to have a circle where the edge thickness is 1/10 of its diameter, so C = 1/10.

Since `Thickness` is a fraction of the horizontal `PlotRange` we have:

```
ThicknessC = Thickness*PlotRange (hor.)
```

and hence, to get the desired edge thickness `ThicknessC`, we have to specify a `Thickness` given by:

```
Thickness =  C * ObjectSizeC / PlotRange (hor.)
```

Similarly, we have:

```
Thickness = AbsoluteThickness / ImageSize
```

and hence,

```
AbsoluteThickness = C * ObjectSizeC * ImageSize / PlotRange (hor.)
```

It seems that any object related edge thickness specification minimally needs to know the final `PlotRange` of the figure, which, on its turn, is determined by all objects in the figure.

If we're going to use `AbsoluteThickness` (but why would we bother?) we'd also need awareness of the `ImageSize` in addition to knowledge about `PlotRange`.

> So, there you have it. The problem can be solved if we can obtain the
>   final `PlotRange`. The question to be asked is: How can we determine
>   the `PlotRange` of a figure while we are drawing it?

Of course, `PlotRange` can be set manually, or be obtained after the fact, but that would mean something ugly like:

```
pr1 = -Subtract @@PlotRange[
        Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.3], Blue}], 
                Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}]][[1]];
pr2 = -Subtract @@ PlotRange[
        Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.3], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}]][[1]];
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.3 pr2/pr1], Blue}], 
          Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}]
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.3], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works, but isn't elegant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `Inset`?

```
disk = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thickness[0.1]}], LightBlue, Disk[]}];

Graphics[{
  Inset[disk, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 1],
  Inset[disk, {2, 0}, {0, 0}, 2],
  Inset[disk, {4, 0}, {0, 0}, 1.5]
}]

Show[%, ImageSize -> 200]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The problem with scaling the circle itself is that I can't put three on a row anymore. I have to go now, so can't try, but could you check this?

Comment: +1 `Inset` seems to solve the problem of the thickness/size ratio. Aligning and scaling of complex objects will need some attention, but that will be doable. Are you aware of any disadvantages of building up graphics from many `Inset`-s? I have yet to test this in combination with `Graph`, but will do that tomorrow.

Comment: @Sjoerd I have created a `Graphics` object with lots of Insets without problem (and `Text` is implemented as `Inset` IIRC), but I cannot recall creating one with many *levels* of Insets, meaning one inside another; that remains to be tested.

Comment: I used this in an update to my [designer's arrow answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11668/57). Works very well! You got my accept. A minor complaint I have is about the whitespace it generates. See note over there. Try the code without the "ShrinkWrap" set to True.

Comment: @Sjoerd Glad I could help, and thanks for the Accept.  Unfortunately I cannot try your code as I do not have FilledCurve but it sure looks spiffy!

Comment: @Sjoerd could you give me a simple v7 compatible example of the extra space?

Comment: Give me a day. Closed the pc for the day and am about to close my iPad too.

Comment: BTW Did you notice that using Inset allowed me to strip GeometricTransform and FindGeometricTransform from the code? Inset is powerful, although there are details you have to take care of, like the PlotRangePadding, which will prevent precise scaling and positioning when forgotten.

Answer (score 11):

Update: Could not get `CurrentValue[..., "ImageSize"]` to pick up the correct image size.

Based on Sjoerd's update, an alternative approach would be to post process a graphics object to transform the thickness primitives using the aspect ratio, plot range and image size of the input graphics. This can be done in a number of ways using `AbsoluteOptions` (getting `PlotRange` or `AspectRatio`) to calculate a new thickness.

Sjoerd's example (slightly modified)

```
 grpSjrd1 = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}],
     Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 300]
grpSjrd2 = Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thickness[0.1], Blue}], Disk[{0, 0}]},
    ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

```
ClearAll[thicknessUnits]; 
thicknessUnits[gr_Graphics, sc_] :=
 With[{units = 
       AbsoluteOptions[gr, AspectRatio][[1, 2]]},
  gr /. EdgeForm[{beg___, Thickness[thcknss_], end___}] :> 
     EdgeForm[{beg, Thickness[sc units ], end}]]
```

Usage examples:

```
Grid[Transpose[
  {thicknessUnits[grpSjrd1, #],thicknessUnits[grpSjrd2, #]} & /@ 
      {.03, .05, .1, .2}], Spacings -> {3, 2}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, one can use the `PlotRange` instead of `AspectRatio`:

```
ClearAll[thicknessUnitsB]; 
thicknessUnitsB[gr_Graphics, sc_] :=
  With[{units =-Subtract @@ AbsoluteOptions[gr, PlotRange][[1, 2, #]] & /@ 
      {1, 2} // (#[[2]]/#[[1]]) & },
   gr /. EdgeForm[{beg___, Thickness[thcknss_], end___}] :> 
   EdgeForm[{beg, Thickness[sc units ], end}]]
```

---

Leftover from original post ... (holding for now until I give up struggling with `CurrentValue[...]`)

Using `CurrentValue["Magnification"]` seems more promising:

```
Column[Style[Graphics[{FaceForm[],
  Dynamic@EdgeForm[{Thickness[.02 CurrentValue["Magnification"]], Blue}],
  Disk[{0, 0}], Disk[{3, 0}], Disk[{6, 0}]}, ImageSize -> 600], 
Magnification -> #] & /@ {.2, .5, 1., 1.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! "ImageSize" was a nice find. It wasn't on my [CurrentValue list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1379/57). I'm not sure about "Magnification"'s utility. I have to check it but it looks like the thickness/object size doesn't remain constant in the last plot.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. `Graphics[{Text[CurrentValue["ImageSize"]]}, ImageSize -> 100]` returns {350,350} not 100. Addition of `Dynamic` doesn't help either.

Comment: The magnification part doesn't work either. The ratio of the circle radius to line thickness for the largest two sets of circles differs by a factor of about 1.5, so it isn't an invariant as was asked for.

Comment: Please, see the update to my question.

Comment: SjoerdC, sorry took a while to respond. I could not get `CurrentValue[... "ImageSize"]` to pick up the image size of the object it resides in. In the light of the update to your question, I will put together an updated post.

Comment: +1, this is much better, though it is similar to the solution I proposed in the update of my question and that I found a bit inelegant (that is, changing the plot after you generated it).  A disadvantage that I see in your current implementation is that it causes all object edges in the plot to have the same relative thickness. It's not a per-object settable option.

Comment: Right, this is the same idea. By changing the replacement rule to `Thickness[sc units thcknss]` we can retain relative thickness differences, but object-specific scaling parameters would take more than the `PlotRange` or `AspectRatio` settings.

Comment: I decided to accept Mr.Wizard's answer as it solves the problem of individualizing the edge thickness better. Thanks for your efforts. You might be interested in the update to my [arrow answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11668/57) using that code.