# How to implement reusable graphic components having stable line thicknesses?

Tags: graphics

**IMPORTANT:** This post is a follow-up to [Scaling edge thicknesses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/scaling-edge-thicknesses), and in particular to the [accepted answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11813/2464) in that thread.

---

Basically, I'm trying to use the idea given in that answer to implement 2-dimensional graphics "components" (i.e. user-defined likes of built-in graphic items such as `Disk` and `Rectangle`) whose line thicknesses will not be subject to the vagaries extensively illustrated in that thread's question.

Here's what the sort of graphics "components" I'm referring to looks like:

```
elements = {Thickness[0.08],
            {Line[{{1, 1}, {1, 5}, {5, 5}, {5, 1}, {1, 1}}], 
             Line[{{1, 3}, {5, 3}}], Line[{{3, 1}, {3, 5}}]}};

component[slot_] := GeometricTransformation[elements, TranslationTransform[{6 (slot - 1), 0}]];

Show[Graphics[Array[component, 1], Background -> LightBlue],
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 80}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...although this one still suffers from "line thickness instability":

```
Show[Graphics[Array[component, 3], Background -> LightBlue],
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 80}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(**NB:** If you think the solution to this problem should be trivial, please read the superb discussion of it in [Scaling edge thicknesses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/scaling-edge-thicknesses).)

---

**NOTES:**

1. the axes and background are not part of the component; I've included them only for reference;
2. as defined above, `component` takes only an integer as argument, corresponding to a horizontal position; this is just to keep the example simple; a more useful component would, at minimum accept a full position vector as argument; more typically, it would also accept an argument specifying its size.

---

I tried to fix this "line thickness instability" by implementing the components in a way that makes use of the `Inset` idea given in the [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11813/2464) mentioned earlier.  More specifically, I tried this:

```
insetComponent[slot_] := Inset[Graphics[elements], {1 + 6 (slot - 1), 0}, {0, 0}, 1];
```

...but it is off to an unauspicious start:

```
Show[Graphics[Array[insetComponent, 1], Background -> LightBlue],
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 80}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am baffled by the appearance of this output.  Anyway, to better see what's going on, I added a tiny bit (?) of `PlotRangePadding`:

```
Show[Graphics[Array[insetComponent, 1], Background -> LightBlue], 
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 80}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

...and made the whole thing bigger to better see what's going on:

```
Show[Graphics[Array[insetComponent, 1], Background -> LightBlue], 
     Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For the life of me, I cannot figure out why the component has been placed where it is...

My question, however, is not about `Inset` per se, but about how to implement *reusable* graphic components (with or without `Inset`), that I can include anywhere within a `Graphics` object (just like a `Disk` or `Rectangle` object), without worrying about their lines growing obese.

(My hope is that `Inset` won't end up introducing instabilities and unpredictabilities of its own.)