# Control line thickness in 2D graphics in terms of original coordinates

Tags: graphics

I would like to create a 2D graphics with lines, connecting points at integer coordinates and control the line's thickness expressed in the original coordinate system. E.g.

```
Line[{{0,0}, {1,0}, {2,1}, ...}]
```

such that the line has a thickness of 0.25 in terms of the coordinate system used for defining the points.

This should resemble the way you can define the radius of a `Tube` in 3D graphics.

Is this possible (in a convenient way)?

I know about `Thickness` (which uses plot-range-relative units) and `AbsoluteThickness` (which uses image-relative units). Neither is suitable, since the plot's range and size are not know in advance (they vary, e.g. inside a `Manipulate`).

This question [Scaling edge thicknesses](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11747/scaling-edge-thicknesses) seems related, but the answers are not really good workarounds. Probably, Wolfram needs to add another option to solve this.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26)

Comment: Can you show a mimimal example of some code where you can demonstrate what you have tried? Especially to show what doesn't work? This would help others understand your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want round corners, `StadiumShape`is a possibility :

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}}
Graphics[Line[data]]
Graphics[StadiumShape[#, 0.25] & /@ Partition[data, 2, 1]]
```

[image]
      [image]

Comment: Good suggestion. I had never heard of `StadiumShape` (apparently, in 3D there is also `CapsuleShape`; you can, however ,accomplish that already through `Tube` with `CapForm["Round"]`). It would have been nice if Mathematica would show `StadiumShape` on the reference page for `Line` under 'See Also'.

It is a bit unfortunate that `StadiumShape` is restricted to single line segments, but mapping it over a partition is not a big deal. Thanks.