# EdgeRenderingFunction and Graph input output structure

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to create an `EdgeRenderingFunction` but the `more information` does not help me at all as far as explaining what the mathematical structure of the input is and at what level , the number of @s, mathematica makes the function act and the mathematical structure of the output.

I would like to be able to create a pure function that does:

- If the initial vertex is "j" then color should be "color[j]"
- If the end vertex is "k" then the thickness should be "Thickness[k]"
- If the relation is `"->"` then the label should be whatever" and position "somewhere", if the relation is `"-"` then the label should be "whateverelse" and position "somewhere else".

Wolfram more information says:

`EdgeRenderingFunction->g specifies that each edge should be rendered with the graphics primitives given by g[{ri..},{vi..},lbij], where ri , rj are the beginning and ending points of the edge,vi ,vj  are the beginning and ending vertices, lbij the  is any label specified for the edge.`

Typically, in math, if `"g"` is a function then `g[something]` signifies that the `"something"`is the ***input*** and `"g[something]"` is the ***output***. But if `"ri"` are coordinates, `"vi"` are vertices and `"lb"` are labels then the `"something"`is intended to be the ***output*** of g[***input***]. So I'm a bit confused by the "more information" and would appreciate some help here.

My other questions are:

1. What is the mathematical structure of the input graph {1->2}?

Someone showed me yesterday in chat but I have forgotten how to replicate it, that:

`{1->2}` is collection of lists where the first list carries the vertices in order

and the second list carries the direction in order.

`{1->2} is stored as {{1,2},{Rule[1,2]}}`

1. what does this Rule look like? How can I write functions on this rule?

Confusingly

```
(#2[[1]] &) @@ {{1, 2}, {"a"}}
a
```

But

```
 (#2[[1]] &) @@ {1 -> 2}
 2
 but with an error message
```

On the other hand

```
 (#[[2]] &) @@ {1 -> 2}
 2
 No errors.
```

So if a `Graph` is stored as a list of lists that I am atting `@@` at a second level then shouldn't I have found the Rule between 1 and 2?

1. How many `@@@` levels is mathematica gonna make my `edgerenderingfunction` act on to the input?

Comment: I think you're asking several unrelated questions here, and an explanation is too long for a comment. Drop by chat to get some guidance, you're complicating things a bit.

Comment: @belisarius thanks. I'm happy to hear that I am complicating things. I'll try to find you in chat sometime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EdgeRenderingFunction` part is not that difficult. The function `g` that you specify in the option `EdgeRenderingFunction->g` gets handed three parameters:

1. A list with begin and end points, so that's a list with *two* 2D vectors/lists
2. A list with the numbers of the begin and end vertices
3. An edge label (if provided)

You can see what is thrown to `EdgeRenderingFunction` by setting the option in a small `GraphPlot` to:

```
EdgeRenderingFunction->(Print[{##}]&)
```

So, g should be a user-defined function of three parameters (or a pure function that uses 0-3 parameters) and that should return graphics instructions. Most often you'll need only the first one (`#1`), to draw some kind of non-standard line.

There are many examples of this given in the documentation, either on the `EdgeRenderingFunction` doc page or the `Graphplot`page. Similar examples can be found for the `Graph`/`EdgeShapeFunction` combo . An application can be found in [the custom arrow question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11545/57).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit swamped this month so I'll respond properly a bit later. Thanks.