# How do I add arrowheads to circular arcs?

Tags: graphics

I have figures containing several arcs showing the extend of angular measures, and would like to indicate the directions in which angles are measured with arrowheads. How do I add an arrowhead at the "ends" of these arcs? (The "arrowheads" panel in the drawing tools palette is, worryingly, disabled.)

For example, I have something like this to start with:

[image]

---

```
Show[
 Graphics[{Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1, {0 Degree, 90 Degree}]}],
 Graphics[{Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.25, {0 Degree, 270 Degree}]}],
 Graphics[{Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5, {0 Degree, 180 Degree}]}]]
```

Comment: Does this help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11545/custom-arrow-shaft

Comment: All I can come up with is something like `Graphics[Arrow[
  BezierCurve[{Sin[#], Cos[#]} & /@ Range[0, Pi, .01]]]]`. That can't be the right approach, can it?

Comment: Since `Arrow[]` can take `BSplineCurve[]` arguments, you can use the functions in [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10957) to get circular arcs with arrow heads. Witness for instance `Arrow[BSplineCurve[{{1, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}, {-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}}, SplineDegree -> 2, SplineKnots -> {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, SplineWeights -> {1, 1/2, 1}]] // Graphics`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705243/how-can-i-make-a-directed-arc-of-a-circle-or-a-directed-curve

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
 Show[ParametricPlot[#[[1]]*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, #[[2]], #[[3]]},
    Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> #[[4]]] /.
  Line[x_] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], Arrow[x]] & /@ 
   {{1, 0 Degree, 90 Degree, Red}, {1.25, 0 Degree, 270 Degree, Blue},
    {1.5, 0 Degree, 180 Degree, Green}},
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Update:** A function using a single `ParametricPlot` with multiple circles with arrows:

```
 ClearAll[arcsWArrows];
 arcsWArrows[args1 : {{_, {_, _}} ..}, dir_List: {Directive[GrayLevel[.3], 
 Arrowheads[{{-0.05, 0}, {0.05, 1}}]]}] :=
   ParametricPlot[ Evaluate[#[[1]]*{ Cos[Rescale[u, {0, 2 Pi}, Abs@#[[2]]]], 
     Sin[Rescale[u, {0, 2 Pi}, Abs@#[[2]]]]} & /@ args1],
    {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> dir, Axes -> False,
     PlotRangePadding -> .2, ImageSize -> 200] /. 
  Line[x_, ___] :> Arrow[x]
```

Usage:

```
rdsAndAngls = {{1, {0, π/2}}, {1.25, {0, π}}, {1.5, {0, (3 π)/2}}, {2, {π/4, (4 π)/2}}};
directives = {Directive[Red, Thick,  Arrowheads[{{-0.05, 0}, {0.05, 1}}]],
    Directive[Blue, Dashed, Arrowheads[{{-0.05, 0}, {0.05, 1}}]],
    Directive[Green, Arrowheads[{{-0.05, 0}, {0.05, 1}}]],
    Directive[Orange, Thickness[.02],  Arrowheads[{{-0.07, 0}, {0.07, 1}}]]};

Row[{arcsWArrows[rdsAndAngls], 
       arcsWArrows[rdsAndAngls, {directives[[1]]}],
       arcsWArrows[rdsAndAngls, directives], 
       arcsWArrows[rdsAndAngls, directives[[-1 ;; 2 ;; -1]]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Would you please add some explanations on what  the part ` Line[x_] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}], Arrow[x]]` is doing. :)

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["SplineCurve"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SplineCircle) to do this:

```
Show[
    Graphics[{
        Red,
        Arrowheads[{-.05,.05}],
        Arrow @ ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0,0}, 1, {1, 0}, {0 Degree, 90 Degree}]
    }],
    Graphics[{
        Blue,
        Arrowheads[{-.05,.05}],
        Arrow @ ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0,0}, 1.25, {1, 0}, {0 Degree, 270 Degree}]
    }],
    Graphics[{
        Green,
        Arrowheads[{-.05,.05}],
        Arrow @ ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0,0}, 1.5, {1, 0}, {0 Degree, 180 Degree}]
    }]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

You can approximate a `Circle` with a `Line` or `Arrow`, if reasonable resolution is given:

```
Circle[o_, r_, {a_, b_}] -> Arrow@Table[{Cos[k], Sin[k]}*r + o, {k, a, b, (b-a)/res}]
```

where `res` gives the resolution of the line. The replacement can be done at the first call of `Graphics` on the arguments or even after, on the `InputForm` version of the resulting figure.

To see it in action:

```
Manipulate[
 pts = N@Table[{Cos[k], Sin[k]}*r + o, {k, α Degree, β Degree, (β Degree - α Degree)/d}];
 Show[
  Graphics[{Lighter@Pink, AbsoluteThickness@10, Circle[o, r, {α Degree, β Degree}]}],
  Graphics[{Arrow[pts, 0]}],
  PlotRange -> {{-1.3, 1.3}, {-1.3, 1.3}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 250
 ],
 {{d, 20, "res."}, 1, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{α, 0, "α"}, 0, 360, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{β, 250, "β"}, 0, 360, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{r, 1, "r"}, 0.01, 2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{o, {0, 0}, "origo"}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: (+1) for nice explanations! :)

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps somebody finds this useful

```
Graphics[{Arrowheads[{-0.05, 0.05}],GraphicsComplex[Table[{Re[Exp[I*g]],Im[Exp[I*g]]},
{g,Subdivide[Pi/4,2/3 Pi, 100]}], Arrow[Range[101]]]},
PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: I should be able to just say `Arrow[Circle[{0,0},1,{0,Pi/4}]]`, but Wolfram's never been one to do things the right way.