# Arrowed circular arc

Tags: graphics

I would like to draw a circular arc with an arrow head, let's say following the
syntax for `Circle[]`:

```
ArcArrow[{x,y},r,{q1,q2}]
```

which should draw an arc between those two angles q1 and q2, with an arrow head at the q2=θ2 end. Is there some way to avoid either (a) the computation of Bezier-curve control points, or (b) a discrete polyline approximation?

Comment: Have a look at: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/how-do-i-add-arrowheads-to-circular-arcs

Comment: Indeed, I think this has already been well covered in the question Kardashev3 linked to (and the questions from it).  Unless you can make the case for me not to I shall close it as a duplicate.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5706674/353410