# What is meant by "curve" in the Mathematica documentation?

Tags: graphics, documentation

My system: Mathematica 11.2

I am missing something major in how to read the on-line help.

Quoting from Mathematica help:

> `Arrow[curve, …]`
>   represents an arrow following the specified curve.

The examples only ever mention splines, Bezier curves and such. But I want to use this feature for a curve I define myself.

For example, for me a circle is a curve. Yet

```
Graphics[Arrow[Circle[{0,0},1]]]
```

gives an error.

What does *curve* mean here?

I am aware of [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13547/1155), so I know how to get a circular arc with an arrow at the end. The code there is mostly Greek to me, but for example

```
Graphics[Arrow[Table[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/24}]]]
```

will produce a circle with an arrow at the end.

So more specificially: *What input will be recognized as a curve by `Arrow`?*

Or, a more meta variant. *Where should I start my studies of the manual to avoid banging my head against walls like this?*

Comment: In the documentation of `Arrow` you will find immediatly some explanations concerning "specification of curves" to be used in `Graphics` and  `Graphics3D`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I cannot find it. The word *curve* is not clickable. Are you saying that `curve` is not something like a datatype with a specified structure?

Comment: I didn't give a"clickable" comment. Look at the answer of m_goldberg (thanks!)

Comment: Jyrki, click on the "Details" section of [`Arrow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html).  Most of the good info on commands is found in these sections of the docs.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelE2. How did I miss that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation article on [Arrow](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html)

> The following curve specifications can be used in Graphics:
>
> $\qquad$Line[…]$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $piecewise line segments
> $\qquad$BezierCurve[…]$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $composite Bezier curve
> $\qquad$BSplineCurve[…]$\ \ \ \ \ \ $B-spline curve
> $\qquad$JoinedCurve[…]$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $joined curve object

Comment: Thanks. *Finding* this was the taxing part. Clicking "Details", as Michael  explained is the step I managed to miss.Thinking that "curve" is datatype like "list".