# How to add arc circular arrows in GeometricTransformation[]

Tags: plotting, graphics, geometry

I am using this code

```
Graphics[{{GeometricTransformation[ 
{ { Thickness[0.0009] , FaceForm[],  Circle[{0, 0}, 1]  } }  ,
 { TranslationTransform[{0, 0}], TranslationTransform[{3, 0}], TranslationTransform[{6, 0}] }  ]} }]
```

and I get Fig. $1$. How can I add the red arc circular arrows in Fig. 2, such that `GeometricTransformation[]` will act on them as with the circle?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the community. Use this code to generate circular arrow `Arrow[BezierCurve[Take[CirclePoints[{0, 0}, {1.2, 1.3}, 180], 20]]]` (`1.2` is radius, `1.3` is rotation, `180` and `20` are for quality and length)

Comment: @BenIzd Thanks. The code you mentioned gives me only a set of numbers.

Comment: You need to include it in your list of Graphics objects. Also, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13547/how-do-i-add-arrowheads-to-circular-arcs

Comment: What do you mean by applying it in the given code, and what is the reason for this constraint(?) ?

Comment: @a20 This code is part of another big code, and, I need to apply them in this code to be able to manage them with the rest of the problem. Is not it possible to add them in this code?

Comment: @Martha97 I still do not understand your constraint. Do you mean that all the code for generating the arrows needs to be written within your Graphics[] function, or can  you e.g. define an arrow-generating function on the lines above and then call this function inside the code above? If the latter is not possible, what is the reason? Both methods are certainly possible, but putting everything within the Graphics[] function will make it very cluttered and non-flexible.

Comment: @a20 No :), your second case is also fine, I mean that for example, I do not know how to combine the two given answers with my code, they only give answers on how to plot an arrow with a circle, I need to, somehow, combine them with my `GeometricTransformation` code. In other words, I should define them for one circle and then use `GeometricTransformation`.

Comment: @a20 I need to put two short arrows on both top and bottom of the circles.

Comment: I have updated the answer to include your particular use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Main idea: Circle can be printed from a initial to a final angle, i.e. an arc can be printed. An arrow(head) can be attached at the end.

```
r = 1;
disp = 0.2;
```

Define a curved arrow object (an arc + an arrowhead):

```
curvedArrowObj[x_, y_, r_, disp_, \[Theta]i_, \[Theta]f_] :=
 {
  Circle[{x, y}, r + disp, {\[Theta]i, \[Theta]f}],
  Arrow[{
    {(r + disp) Cos[\[Theta]f - 6 Degree],
     (r + disp)  Sin[\[Theta]f - 6 Degree]},
    {(r + disp)  Cos[\[Theta]f + 6 Degree],
     (r + disp)  Sin[\[Theta]f + 6 Degree]}
    }
   ]
  }
```

Usage:

```
Graphics[{
  Blue,
  Circle[{0, 0}, r],
  Red,
  Arrowheads[Medium],
  curvedArrowObj[0, 0, r, disp, \[Pi]/6, \[Pi]/3],
  curvedArrowObj[0, 0, r, disp + 0.2, 120 Degree, 225 Degree],
  Black,
  Arrowheads[Large],
  curvedArrowObj[0, 0, r, disp, 160 Degree, 190 Degree]
  }
 ,
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
 ]
```

[image]

**EDIT1 Example for OP's particular case**

```
Graphics[{
  GeometricTransformation[
   {
    {
     Thickness[0.0009],
     FaceForm[],
     Circle[{0, 0}, 1], 
     Red,
     Arrowheads[Small],
     curvedArrowObj[0, 0, 1, 0.2, 75 Degree, 105 Degree],
     curvedArrowObj[0, 0, 1, 0.2, 255 Degree, 285 Degree]
     }
    },
   {
    TranslationTransform[{0, 0}],
    TranslationTransform[{3, 0}],
    TranslationTransform[{6, 0}]}
   ]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but I disagree on the use of `Subscript` in `Subscript[\[Theta], i]`. That shouldn't be encouraged, except when formatting displays.

Comment: I agree and thanks for the feedback. It started out that way and is not a part of the function. I will update this aspect soon.

Comment: How would it be for Grahpics3D?

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar, see [SplineCircle](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SplineCircle/) for examples. For arrows, you need to replace lines with tubes. If you have a specific application in mind, you can start a new post.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [`ResourceFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ResourceFunction) ["SplineCircle"](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SplineCircle) to create a [`BSplineCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BSplineCurve) version of an arc that can be directly used inside of [`Arrow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow):

```
obj={
    Circle[{0,0}],
    Red, 
    Arrowheads->Small,
    Arrow @ ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0,0}, 1.1, {0,1},{-.3,.3}],
    Arrow @ ResourceFunction["SplineCircle"][{0,0}, 1.1, {0,-1},{-.3,.3}]
};
```

Using the above object inside of `GeometricTransformation`:

```
Graphics[{
    obj, 
    GeometricTransformation[
        obj,
        {TranslationTransform[{2.5,0}],TranslationTransform[{-2.5,0}]}
    ]
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

A start...

```
Graphics[{
  Red, Arrow[BSplineCurve[Table[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, Pi, Pi/10}]]],
  Black, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.9]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: BSplineCurve[] is no good due to its limited polynomial approximation of the curve. The straight lines at the beginning and end of the curve are very noticable, and if you put the same radius of the inner circle you will see that your BSplineCurve has a smaller radius.