# How can I separate the dress from the background?

Tags: image-processing

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyIK.jpg"]
```

[image: dress]

The dress is closely similar with the color of the background stair rail.

How can I binarize the image to get the dress mask or human mask?

Any methods of Binarize is acceptable, like 
`RegionBinarize`, training an semantic segment model

I've tried several `Binarize*` functions, and `EdgeDetect` functions, and confirmed that there are some challenges in the right-down part of the dress.

Background explaination: Why to segment?
For example, consider there are many dress model pictures, we can cluster them by dress, and remove background we could get better features, for example textures and shapes.

---

## upadte:

Maybe someone knows more about traditional segment methods and has various experiences.
Thanks for @rhermans 's comment.

`RemoveBackground[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyIK.jpg‌​"], {"Foreground", {RGBColor[ 0.9157048167754652, 0.8904987221508752, 0.8709273742640429], 0.062}}]`

ImagePartition is a good idea with better region effect in Watershed.

```
WatershedComponents[,mask]//Colorize
```

[image]

Comment: I always don't think there is any efficient-universel method to do this.

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132844/5467)

Comment: Do you want the left forearm and hand in front of the dress removed as well?

Comment: Also, are you concerned only with this particular image or are you looking for general method that would on other images with a similar problem?

Comment: I think one way would be to define a `Mask` manually (related [How to retouch (smart fill) photo image?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120507/how-to-retouch-smart-fill-photo-image)). Or you can try splitting your image into segments  for better contrast 
    `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyIK.jpg"];Grid[Partition[EdgeDetect[#] & /@ (ImagePartition[img, 50]~Flatten~1),
   4], Spacings -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: Do you need a fully automated procedure or can you afford doing steps by hand? 
I think you should [edit] your question and explain better what you need. As it stands, the question is too broad.

Comment: `RemoveBackground[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyIK.jpg"], {"Foreground", {RGBColor[
   0.9157048167754652, 0.8904987221508752, 0.8709273742640429], 
   0.062}}]`

Comment: @rhermans I'm sorry,that [work for you](http://i.stack.imgur.com/k1Y6Y.png)?

Comment: Why do you want to remove the dress?

Comment: @yode, I don't think is possible to separate the dress from the rest of the white background without working "by hand", the code I put was as far as I think make sense to go, unless the question is better defined.

Comment: @m_goldberg yes, without hands and arms, I found it's easy to segment the skin area.

Comment: @m_goldberg The datasets are limit in model dress pictures here.  May be a particular method suit to the particular image can be generalized to more similar background pictures.

Comment: @Sumit ImagePartition is a good idea! much better for Watershed in global image.

Comment: @bills see update, I found it's hard, and then it could be an good excercise.

Answer (score 4):

My take at this—not perfect by any means.

The main feature I would exploit is that the area you want to segment is spatially well defined, so you can combine the color information with the position one.

Let's first define a `white` mask:

```
white = Binarize[ColorDistance[i, Darker[White, .1]], {0, .1}]
```

[image: white_mask]

and a white stripe inside the image boundary:

```
border = ImagePad[ImagePad[0 i, -60], 60, 1];
```

We can now combine them in a `backgroundMask` and a `foregroundMask`

```
backgroundMask = Erosion[border + ColorNegate[white], 3];
foregroundMask = Erosion[ColorNegate[border], BoxMatrix[{60, 30}]] * white;

{backgroundMask, foregroundMask}
```

[image: component_mask]

and use them in `GrowCutComponents` to assign the remaining pixels.

```
mask = Image[
   GrowCutComponents[i, {backgroundMask, foregroundMask}] - 1
];
```

The result is not perfect—no spoilers here—but almost all the extra white has been removed

```
SetAlphaChannel[i, Blur[Erosion[mask, 2], 1]]
```

[image: dress_alpha]

You can tweak the code to make the boxes a little more asymmetric and improve the segmentation area, but—as others have said—there's a limit to where automatic (non semantic) segmentation can take you.

Comment: `MaxDetect[img, .2]` will give your `white`

Comment: @yode only for pure white though—`GrayLevel[1]`.

Comment: see my answer, the Neural Network is very useful

Answer (score 4):

Cool result of NetModel of 11.3.

You can download the models like `Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on PASCAL VOC2012 and MS-COCO Data` from [Wolfram Netmodel Reposity](http://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository)

Open the Notebook, then import the sample image, and run the code.

```
img=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyIK.jpg"]
result[img]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @C.E. I've added an link, you can download the example notebook there

Comment: @C.E. OK, I think in this example, it's needless to copy codes from official help examples into answer.

Comment: @C.E. Comment cann't show image. This method solved my question greatly, I think its useful for many other people.

Comment: @C.E. The most useful point is one know there are some NN models in Mathematica 11.3 to do such an thing.

Comment: @C.E. How about now? is it like a answer?

Comment: Using an image segmentation network is a pretty good idea; I don't see what the problem is with this answer. However, it would be better to just give the complete code that downloads the network from within a notebook. I.e., `resource = "Ademxapp Model A1 Trained on PASCAL VOC2012 and MS-COCO Data"; ResourceObject[resource]; net = NetModel[resource]; net[img]`. Furthermore, it seems like this network doesn't get you all the way to the final answer, though it's definitely useful as a first step in defining a mask for further segmentation analysis.

Comment: I deleted my comments because there is no reason for them to forever mar this answer. I still believe that this answer could be better though, Sjoerd said it pretty well.