# Another difficult background subtraction

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to remove the background but it is removing part of the bag in the foreground (because it is white too):

[image]

Here's what I've tried:

```
img = Import["https://i.imgur.com/PHY5rwj.jpg"];
fg = RemoveBackground[img, {"Background", White}];
RemoveAlphaChannel[fg, LightBlue]
```

[image]

I have thousands of these types of images so it isn't possible for me to add a mask for each one. Ideally, I would be able to remove the person as well and just have the bag left, although I don't think that is possible.

**Additional examples:**

```
CloudGet@CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/78a79bbb-16b6-424b-8436-4e2e24f7d228"]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have higher-resolution images, or is the image in your question the highest resolution you have?

Comment: Furthermore, it would be useful to add more than a single (extremely low-resolution) image to your post so that people can see if their solution works across multiple examples.

Comment: @CarlLange The hyperlinked image is {545, 545}, if that's not enough I could try to make them bigger.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I actually just used the image you embedded, which is 100*100. Would still recommend adding a few images to the post, not just one.

Comment: Actually that’s the max size that I have.

Comment: @CarlLange Ok, I just added a few more examples.

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer, because I suggest using an image processing application such as Adobe Photoshop OR the free GIMP. Those apps have "magic wand" selection and other tools to do this kind of processing, quickly and easily. If you don't have a color-contrasting background (like blue or green) or luminance contrasting BG (black) then magic-wand selection typically gives the best results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution more-or-less works for this particular case, but it's not going to be a general solution. However, as you only have the one image in your question this is all I have to go on for now:

```
SetAlphaChannel[i, 
 ColorNegate@
  DeleteSmallComponents@FillingTransform@MorphologicalPerimeter[i, 8]]
```

[image]

As you can see, this works for the general background and does not remove the bag - however, it also doesn't remove the background around the handle of the bag or at the bottom left of the image. It also has clear issues around the hair and borders, and the zip has some slight removal.

The main parameter here is the one for `MorphologicalPerimeter`, but `FillingTransform` and `DeleteSmallComponents` also have parameters currently set to `Automatic`.

It may be possible to use a neural network to semantically segment the image and remove the backgrounds that way. I answered [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172908/fashion-segmentation-with-a-neural-net/189168#189168) question with an example of how to train one of these networks from scratch, or you could adapt something like [this network](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Ademxapp-Model-A1-Trained-on-ADE20K-Data) to do this, though neither is a straightforward, 100% accuracy approach.

Comment: Thanks, Did you see the other examples I just added them

Comment: It doesn't do that badly on the additional examples.

Comment: @M.R. Yes, I agree, it does OK on the additional examples but it's still not that great. If the ~75% accuracy works for you, that's great, but otherwise I think a neural network approach is good (especially if you want to also remove the human). Unfortunately I don't have the time to spare to do that :)

Comment: Time and data!!

Comment: How would you generate training data?

Comment: I wouldn't. The dataset in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172908/fashion-segmentation-with-a-neural-net/189168#189168 would suffice.

Comment: See I think it's too few images to make a robust solution

Comment: I would recommend doing some transfer learning with [this network or similar](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Ademxapp-Model-A1-Trained-on-ADE20K-Data) and that dataset, if you are worried about a lack of data. Unfortunately I can't help any further with this question.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like this, estimating the background from the median pixel value. It works (more or less) when the background value is the most abundant pixel value. Obviously (as seen in the last image), if fails when the object takes up most of the image and there are not enough background pixels.

`img =`

[image]

```
imgsub = {};
Do[{
   m = Median[Flatten[ImageData[i]]];
   a1 = ColorNegate[Binarize[i, Min[m + .015, .99]]];
   AppendTo[imgsub, RemoveAlphaChannel[SetAlphaChannel[i, a1], Blue]];
   }, {i, img}];
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Randomly selecting some pixels, I noted that for RGB values, the white background has RGB colors of around (250,250,250) up to (255,255,255), while the purse has a whitish color of around (240,240,240) to about (245,245,245).
Just select pixels with value R+G+B >=750 and that should get most of the background. I'd use a neural net for more intermediate colors, but mostly black and mostly white are the simplest colors to select. No MMA with me right now, but coding should be straight forward.