# Detection of regions in image

Tags: image-processing

I have this image:

[image]

I would like to separate qualitatively 4 different regions into approximately such an image:

[image]

The colors or gray shadings of the regions do not matter.

How can this be achieved with Mathematica?

Comment: The easiest way I can think of of the top of my head is a neural network, but for that you would need a fair bit of labeled data to train with. If you do have plenty of data, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172908/fashion-segmentation-with-a-neural-net/189168#189168) may be a starting point.

Comment: Do you know that there are always 4 regions?

Comment: Also, you should provide proper unmodified example data. The image in the post is upscaled. It looks like a screenshot.

Comment: @Carl Lange: In this image there are 4 regions. Those are bright objects of different size and density on top of a dark background. Are there no Image Segmentation functions which can solve this (only) qualitatively?

Comment: Another option is something like `ImageFilter[
 Module[{m = Mean@Flatten@#},
   If[m < .25, .25,
    If[.5 > m >= .25, .5,
     If[.75 > m >= .5, .75,
      If[
       m >= .75, 1]]]]
   ] &, ImageAdjust@i, 10]`, and changing the tolerances, although I'm sure there are better ways to write that code.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I don't have something better … ist a screenshot from a publication.

Comment: You could have linked to the publication.

Comment: You might want to try this Fiji plugin (it's not Mathematica though): https://imagej.net/Labkit

Comment: If it's from a publication, then you could open the PDF in Acrobat and do an "Export All Images" to get raw image data to upload.

Comment: `ClusteringComponents` could help, but it has a ton of options and knobs requiring a lot of experimentation. Something like `image=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfLp.png"]; Colorize@ClusteringComponents[image, Method -> {"Spectral", "NeighborhoodRadius" -> 0.2}]` but with better parameters and more post-processing.

Comment: Something to try is `GaborFilter[]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will rely on the assumption that the noise will blend into different intensities for each desired component.

A Kuwahara filter is good at removing uniform noise from an image while preserving edges. Here the noise is 'locally uniform' and the edges we seek are the boundaries where the noise noticeably changes. So a Kuwahara filter can help, but admittedly might not be the best choice of filter for this task:

```
im = ColorConvert[RemoveAlphaChannel[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfLp.png"]], "Grayscale"];
kuw = KuwaharaFilter[im, 10]
```

[image]

This filter uses a square kernel and therefore looks splotchy. We can do our best to smooth it:

```
smooth = ImageAdjust[CurvatureFlowFilter[MeanFilter[kuw, 10], 50]];
```

Before and after:

```
{im, smooth}
```

[image]

From here we can cluster, but note that my attempt is hand wavy and misses the 4th component:

```
cov = DominantColors[smooth, Automatic, "CoverageImage"];

HighlightImage[im, 
 MapIndexed[{ColorData[111] @@ #2, 
    DeleteSmallComponents[FillingTransform[#]]} &, cov]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As an option

```
image = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWfLp.png"];
im = ImageData[image];


d = ImageDimensions[image];

f = Interpolation[
   Flatten[Table[{i, j, First[im[[i, j]]]}, {i, 1, d[[2]]}, {j, 1, 
      d[[1]]}], 1]];



ImageReflect[
 DensityPlot[f[x, y], {y, d[[1]], 1}, {x, 1, d[[2]]}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 200, Frame -> False]]
```

[image: fig1]

Can also be used

```
t = Flatten[
   Table[{i, j, First[im[[i, j]]]}, {i, 1, d[[2]]}, {j, 1, d[[1]]}], 
   1];

ListDensityPlot[t, Frame -> False, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Clustering gives a less clear result.

```
ClusteringComponents[image, 6] // Colorize
```

[image: fig2]

Comment: I don't see how this answers the OP's question. You did not segment the image into the four requested regions.

Comment: @Szabolcs I hope that OP understands the criterion by which he identified 4 areas. He himself did not offer any code.