# How to author a workflow?

Tags: graphics, documentation, undocumented, drawing

I find the workflow refpages in the doc center very helpful, and I'd like to make some of my own:

[image]

Workflows seem to be notebooks of `"Text"` and `"AnnotatedOutput"` cells riffled together, and the graphics in them look like they came from "Drawing Tools":

[image]

So, *how can I make a similar diagram from multiple images* (typically screenshots) with those nifty width-changing green arrows?

- I think a palette solution would be best here.
- I don't want to use the *drawing tools*, becuase that usually crashes for me
- Prefer to use a mouse-drag to make the arrows that go from a certain point in the first subimage to another point in the next, rather than having to give specific coordinates...
- Does anyone know if it's an undocumented built-in package?

Comment: I saw this on a [recent live stream](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/517545127), starting around 1:18:33.  Part of the (internal to WRI) DocuTools.

Comment: DocuTools is not available to public.  So is there a way to author workflow without it?

Comment: @QuantumDot I think if you install workbench you can extract it from the stuff that Eclipse provides. It’s possible to open up a notebook inside workbench, find the location of the paclets, then copy them out to the standard location in the layout. At that point they’ll work without asking you to use Eclipse.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Oh, then do I understand DocuTools *is* actually available through Workbench/Eclipse?  In that case, I am error.

Comment: @b3m2a1 The publicly available version of DocuTools is very old and doesn't include Workflows (see the livestream I linked to for a look at the current internal DocuTools).

Comment: @ChrisK Ah figures. Too bad.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Using `annotationArrow` with [`LocatorPane`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocatorPane.html) to have multiple annotation arrows (use ALT+Click to create new locators or to remove existing ones):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0KML.png"]
```

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {#, {0, 1} + #} & @(ImageDimensions[img]/2)}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  Dynamic[Show[img, 
    Graphics[{RGBColor[0, 2/3, 2/3], 
      Dynamic[annotationArrow[#]] & /@ Partition[pt, 2]}, 
     ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[img]]]], 
  Appearance -> None, 
  LocatorAutoCreate -> True]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

For the arrow glyph only:

Using the function `arow` from [this answer by Simon Woods](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11667/125) to construct a glyph that looks like the annotation arrow in OP:

```
ClearAll[annotationArrow]
annotationArrow = {EdgeForm[], RGBColor[0, 2/3, 2/3], 
    arow[If[#[[1, 1]] > #[[2, 1]], 1, -1] 1.6, 0., 0., 0., 0.5, 0.9, 0.04, 0., .95][#]} &;

Row[Graphics[annotationArrow[#], ImageSize -> Medium] & /@ 
  {{{0, 0}, {0, -.5}}, {{0, 0}, {-.001, -.5}}, 
   {{0.01, -.5}, {0, 0}}, {{-0.01, -.5}, {0, 0}}}, Spacer[30]]
```

[image]

Add `Locator`s to control the coordinates of the tip and the tail of the arrow:

```
Deploy @ DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0, .5}, pt2 = {0, -1}}, 
  Graphics[{Locator[Dynamic[pt1], None], Locator[Dynamic[pt2], None], 
    RGBColor[0, 2/3, 2/3], Dynamic[annotationArrow[{pt1, pt2}]]}, 
   ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: It’d be pretty hard to use this to make a full workflow without doing a bunch of work to make a nice palette. Moreover, this won’t handle any of the documentation metadata or any of that.

Comment: @b3m2a1, right. Should have mentioned this is just the glyph.

Comment: If you stuck the glyph inside some palette that’d build a `GraphicColumn` and then put the glyph on top of that I’m sure that’d be something people would find very cool.

Comment: Love the arrow, but how to add more and more images and arrows?

Comment: Need a UIFold[]

Comment: @M.R. make it into a `GraphicsColumn`. Then you can add stuff by appending to the first argument of the column.

Comment: Graphicscolumns generally cause lots of problems for me, in terms of slowness and resizing

Comment: @M.R. they can be a pain in the ass, but in this case I think it's the right tool for the job