# Marking distance with an arrow that has lead lines

Tags: plotting

I have:

```
f[x_] = 5 - 4/25*x^2.2;
Plot[{f[x], f[1] + (f[4] - f[1])/(4 - 1)*(x - 1), 
  f[1] + f'[1] (x - 1)}, {x, 0, 4.5},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {0, 6}},
 PlotLegends -> {"f", "secant", "tangent"},
 Epilog -> {
   Red, PointSize[Large], Point[{{1, f[1]}, {4, f[4]}}],
   Black, Line[{{1, f[1]}, {4, f[1]}, {4, f[4]}}],
   Text[Style["f", Black, Background -> White], {4.5, f[4.5]}],
   Text[Style["(x,f(x))", Black, Background -> White], {1, 
     f[1]}, {1.2, 1.2}],
   Text[Style["(x+Δx,f(x+Δx))", Black, 
     Background -> White], {4, f[4]}, {1.2, 1.2}],
   Text[Style["dx=Δx", Black, 
     Background -> White], {2.5, f[1]}, {0, -1.2}],
   },
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0, 0.03}]
 ]
```

[image]

Now I'd like to add the distance labels dy and $\Delta x$ on the right-hand side. What's the best way to draw an arrow with arrow heads and each end and a little horizontal line above and below the arrowhead tip? I know I can do it with Graphics, but just wondering if there is already an arrowhead style that might do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can design custom arrowheads!  Define

```
arrow = Graphics[{
  FilledCurve[{
    Line[{
      {-1.5, 0.}, {-1.5, 0.}, {-1.95, 1.05}, {0., 0.}
      , {0., -1.05}, {0.15, -1.05}, {0.15, 1.05}, {0., 1.05}
      , {0., 0.}, {-1.95, -1.05}, {-1.5, 0.}
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Then, in your code, you can make two-headed arrows using

```
Arrowheads[{{0.015, 1, arrow}, {-0.015, 0, arrow}}]
```

Resizing is done by way of changing the numbers `0.015` and `-0.015`. If we add the above `Arrowheads` call and

```
Arrow[{{4.5, 5}, {4.5, 1.5}}]
```

to `Epilog`, the result looks like this:

[image]

---

Here's how I came up with the code for `arrow` (for the most part). We use the amazing arrowhead creator from [this answer by Sjoerd C. de Vries](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7105/29734) and adapt it for our purposes.

First, copy and paste his first `DynamicModule` and add

```
Line[{
 top
 , {top[[1]], rightBase[[2]]}
 , {top[[1]] + 0.15, rightBase[[2]]}
 , {top[[1]] + 0.15, -rightBase[[2]]}
 , {top[[1]], -rightBase[[2]]}, top}
]
```

between `BSplineCurve[{leftBase, outerMidLeft, top}]` and `BSplineCurve[{top, outerMidRight, rightBase}]`. This extra bit of code will create the line at the end of the arrowhead. Then, play with the `Locator`s for awhile until we get an arrowhead that looks nice. I chose the following:

[image]

As outlined in the answer linked above, we define

```
arrow = h /. Opacity[_] :> Sequence[];
```

To make things more general, you can add new `Locator`s that define the positions of the bar at the end of the arrow in order to play around with how the arrow looks. Finally, to get the `arrow` as defined at the beginning of the post, I actually did

```
arrow = h /. BSplineCurve -> Line
  /. Opacity[_] :> Sequence[]
  /. a_?NumberQ :> Round[a, 0.15]
  //. {Line[{a__, b_}], Line[{x_, y__}], z___} :> {Line[{a, b, y}], z}
```

The third replacement is unnecessary, but I did it so that the code would format nicely.