# Adapting old Arrow expressions

Tags: graphics, replacement, expression-construction

I have an old notebook that uses the now obsolete `Arrow` package.
For example, I have an expression containing

```
Arrow[{1,2}, {6,7}, HeadLength -> 0.005, HeadCenter -> 0.5]
```

I suppose I know how to translate this in absence of options. I should have

```
Arrow[{{1,2}, {6,7}}]
```

but how can I obtain the same arrow shape as given by the old-style options using `Arrowheads`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can replace old arrows to new with the following pattern

```
arw = Arrow[pt__List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
  {Arrowheads[HeadLength] /. {opts, HeadLength -> Automatic}, Arrow[{pt}]};

Graphics[Arrow[{1, 2}, {6, 7}, HeadLength -> 0.1]] /. arw
```

> ```
> Graphics[{Arrowheads[0.1], Arrow[{{1, 2}, {6, 7}}]}]
> ```

[image]

`Arrowheads` specifies the length of arrowheads as a fraction of the total width of the graphic. If you need another behavior see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/788/4678) question.

To take into account `HeadCenter` and `HeadWidth` you can specify your own graphics for the arrowheads

```
arw2 = Arrow[pt__List, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :> 
 {Arrowheads[{{HeadLength, Automatic, 
    Graphics@{EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@{{-1, HeadWidth/2}, {0, 0}, 
        {-1, -HeadWidth/2}, {-HeadCenter, 0}}}}}] /. 
    {opts, HeadLength -> Automatic, HeadCenter -> 1, HeadWidth -> 0.5}, 
  Arrow[{pt}]};

Show[Graphics[Table[Arrow[{0, 0}, {Sin[x], Cos[x]},
     HeadCenter -> x, HeadLength -> 0.1] /. arw2,
   {x, 0, 1.6, 0.2}],
  PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 1}, {-0.2, 1.1}}]]
```

[image]

It is very close to the [original behavior](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Graphics/Arrow.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the pattern, but I prefer not to use it and  switch to the new format. I wonder were in the Help System they say that `Arrowheads[{{a,b}}]` has the same meaning of the old `HeadLength->a` and `HeadCenter->b`.

Comment: @enzotib I mean that the pattern will help you to automate the process of converting if you have a huge number of this arrows.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. But I am now realizing there is an interpretation error, because the old `HeadCenter` gave the position of the junction marked with the red circle in this image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/503888/arrow.png

Comment: @enzotib OK, now I understand better. See my update!

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.