# Fix the size of vertices and arrow in graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

I defined an option to draw nicely the graph. But I have a problem with the different size obtained. For example, the layout of the first graph is what I want to have for all other graphs I will define later. But for smaller graphs, their vertices look biger and biger. It seems that there is a way to control this using `Scale`, but I don't want to adjust this for each graph I will have.

Is there a way to specify the size of vertices and edges once for all?

```
ef2[el_, ___] := {RGBColor[0, 0, 1], Thickness[1/200], Arrowheads[1/16], Arrow[el, 0.2]}

options = Sequence[VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> 1/2,
VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}], VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, White], 
GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", EdgeShapeFunction -> ef2, ImageSize -> 400];

g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 8 -> 7, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 9}, options]
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 7, 3 -> 1, 5 -> 6, 5 -> 9}, options]
g = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 7, 3 -> 7}, options]
g = Graph[{1 -> 2}, options]
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know of two methods to produce a fixed vertex size.

### `Scaled`

Use [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scaled.html) for [`VertexSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/VertexSize.html) and set `AspectRatio -> 1`:

```
options = Sequence[VertexStyle -> Black, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}],
    VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, White], GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> ef2, ImageSize -> 400, VertexSize -> Scaled[{0.1, 0.1}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
```

[image]

### `Offset`

As demonstrated  in [How can I specify the arrowhead size in printers points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/788/how-can-i-specify-the-arrowhead-size-in-printers-points/797#797) if you construct a `Graphics` expression using [`Offset`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Offset.html) coordinates it will be rendered at a fixed size.

```
vf[xy_, _, _] := {Red, Rectangle[Offset[{-1, -1} 15, xy], Offset[{1, 1} 15, xy]]}

options = Sequence[VertexStyle -> Black, VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", {Center, Center}],
   VertexLabelStyle -> Directive[16, White], GraphLayout -> "CircularEmbedding", 
   EdgeShapeFunction -> ef2, ImageSize -> 400, VertexShapeFunction -> vf];
```

[image]