# what causes this display problem (missing arrows) with this adjacency graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

```
AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

If you look very closely at the resulting visual display in a notebook (below), you can see narrowing where the arrow heads might be.  Many adjacency graphs display without problem.  What is causing this display problem?  Is there a general but not complex approach (i.e., an approach suitable to real-time classroom display) to avoiding this problem?  (Mma version 10.2 on Win 7.)

[image: graph plot with missing arrows]

Comment: There were questions about this before, but I cannot find them.  Yes, this is very annoying. It happens because the arrowhead size is a fixed fraction of the image *width*. If the image is narrow, the arrowheads are small, sometimes literally invisible. Consider using the option `EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium]` which forces an absolute measurement independent of the image size.  Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/788/12  You can also consider complaining to Wolfram Support, maybe they'll give this more priority then ...

Comment: Actually, looking more carefully, this is fixed in version 10.3.  David's answer doesn't show it because that display of the graph is wide.  But `PathGraph[Range[3], DirectedEdges -> True, GraphLayout -> "LayeredDigraphEmbedding"]` does.  The arrowheads are invisible in 10.2 and look fine in 10.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Mathematica* 10.3,

```
 AdjacencyGraph[{{1, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

yields

[image]

Comment: You are right: it did get fixed in 10.3.  But this example does not show that.  Please see my comments under the question.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it meets my needs, but I understand @Szabolcs reservations and his suggestion to use `EdgeStyle -> Arrowheads[Medium]`.  Thanks!